# Restore .backup PostgreSQL in JAVA (No .exe) cross OS

Tags: java, postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.3

I want to restore a local (.backup) Database in PostgrSQL using JAVA but I don't want to use the pg_restore.exe method (i need it to be used with all OSs like Windows, Linux..). 
I tried this function but it doesn't work and it has the .exe

```
public static void RestoreWin() throws IOException{
 Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process p;
 //ProcessBuilder pb;
 r = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
 String[] cmd = {
    "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_restore.exe",
    "--host", "localhost",
    "--port", "5432",
    "--username", "postgres",
    "--dbname", "db_test",
    "--password","password",
    "--verbose",
    "C:\\db_test.backup"
    };
    p = r.exec(cmd);
}
```

Is there another solution in Java? 
Thank you.

Comment: The only way to restore a custom format backup **is** to run `pg_restore`.

Comment: Is there a way to use the Postgres console through Java?

Comment: `pg_restore` is a regular operating system executable (not a "postgres console"). You should be able to run that using (the deprecated) `Runtime.exec()` or (recommended) `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Why? What's the problem you're trying to solve here? Why not just invoke `pg_restore`?